# Humidity specification - is there a typical reason for a non-zero minimum?

Tags: humidity

I'm curious about reasoning in specifying the *lower limit* for humidity. Looking at a common and thoroughly documented device we interact with, the Siemens S7-1500 PLC, it specifies RH = 5%-95%

- Is there a typical reason for the lower limit being non-zero?
- Are there common electronic or wiring components that don't last if they're extremely dry?

Comment: Good question... at a *guess*, that is the regime over which the device has been tested, because it's difficult to achieve lower RH in a production test environment. However, very low humidity increases risk of electrostatic discharge: https://airinnovations.com/blog/humidity-impact-electronics-manufacturing/ , which *might* be a factor.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I also thought of the ESD risk of lower humidity, but it gets bad well above 5%, so not sure if that's a factor.

Comment: @JohnD, that's shocking! (with apologies for my revolting sense of humor)

Comment: It might be that it is not sensible to test below 5%, if testing would need more expensive equipment and more time to test it. 5% is anyway much lower than humans feel comfortable living and working, and if some indusrtrial setting requires less, you can always keep the PLC somewhere else than in the less than 5% area.

Comment: @Justme - thanks. I'm looking at a peripheral module in that kind of system, and am certain there will be no actual complaints setting a 5% lower limit from customer. I was more curious about what the failure mechanism is that's driving the limit, if there is one that stands out - to potentially preemptively phase out vulnerable components